# Having trouble finding the correct web page to scrape the data - web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the price for a list of courses on this [website](https://www.learningconnection.philips.com/en/catalog).

However, I'm having trouble finding the page where I can see the entire list of courses and their prices.

I was able to come up with below code, which pulls the price for a single course:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
url = "https://www.learningconnection.philips.com/en/course/pinnacle%C2%B3-advanced-planning-education"
html = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
price = soup.select_one("[class*='field-price'] .even").text
print(price)
```

Any help/suggestions appreciated!

Comment: there are a very large number of courses. You would need a spider to crawl down the links and possibly do a set on results. For example, is there overlap between courses under Clinical Informatics and Biomedical engineers? Or is it that you have a specific profession/product/clinical focus in mind and are only interested in the courses within that domain? Perhaps see [here](https://www.learningconnection.philips.com/en/catalog/profession/health-educators) and determine which filters need to be applied.

Comment: Yes I'm particularly interested in courses for the "Biomedical Engineers" :https://www.learningconnection.philips.com/en/catalog/profession/biomedical-engineers, under which there are 3 sub modalities, so about 24 courses in total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of looping down through that area of interest. Uses bs4 4.7.1 + is order to have access to `:contains`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

base = 'https://www.learningconnection.philips.com'
url = f'{base}/en/catalog/profession/biomedical-engineers'
courses = []
results = []

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get(url)
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    links = [base + i['href'] for i in soup.select('h3 a')]
    for link in links:
        r = s.get(link)
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        courses+=[i['href'] for i in soup.select('.title a')]
    for course in courses:
        r = s.get(course)
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        price = soup.select_one('em:contains("Tuition:")')
        if price is None:
            price = 'Not listed'
        else:
            price = price.text.replace('\xa0',' ')
        result = {'Title':soup.select_one('#page-title').text.replace('\xa0',' ')
                 ,'Description': soup.select_one('.field-item p').text.replace('\xa0',' ')
                 ,'Price': price
                 , 'Url':course}
        results.append(result)

print(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the price by anchoring your search on the item's parent wrapper:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
d = soup(requests.get('https://www.learningconnection.philips.com/en/course/pinnacle%C2%B3-advanced-planning-education').text, 'html.parser')
prices = [i.find_all('div', {'class':'field-item even'})[2].text for i in d.find_all('fieldset', {'class':' group-overview field-group-fieldset panel panel-default form-wrapper'})]
```

Output:

```
['5141.00']
```

Comment: Thanks for response.  This seems to be an alternative way to retrieve price for this particular course though?  What I'm looking for is the page to scrape all courses.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Key-Word to search the item and then based on that search results get all the urls. Once you get the urls loop it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
Search_key='pinnacle'
url = "https://www.learningconnection.philips.com/en/search/site/{}".format(Search_key)
html = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
urls=[item['href'] for item in soup.select('h3.title > a')]
price=[]
for url in urls:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')
    if soup.select_one("[class*='field-price'] .even"):
        price.append(soup.select_one("[class*='field-price'] .even").text)
print(price)
```

**Output:**

```
['5171.00', '5171.00', '3292.00', '5141.00', '4309.00', '2130.00', '2130.00', '2130.00']
```

---

You can also print the course title.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
Search_key='pinnacle'
url = "https://www.learningconnection.philips.com/en/search/site/{}".format(Search_key)
html = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
urls=[item['href'] for item in soup.select('h3.title > a')]
price=[]
title=[]
for url in urls:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')
    if soup.select_one("[class*='field-price'] .even"):
        title.append(soup.select_one("h1#page-title").text)
        price.append(soup.select_one("[class*='field-price'] .even").text)
print(title)
print(price)
```

**Output:**

```
['Pinnacle³ Auto Segmentation with SPICE', 'Pinnacle³ Dynamic Planning', 'Pinnacle³ Additional Education', 'Pinnacle³ Advanced Planning Education', 'Pinnacle³ Basic Planning Education', 'Pinnacle³ Physics Modeling', 'Pinnacle³ Level I Basic Planning Education', 'Pinnacle³ Level II Education']
['5171.00', '5171.00', '3292.00', '5141.00', '4309.00', '2130.00', '2130.00', '2130.00']
```

---

**Edited**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
Search_key='biomed'
url = "https://www.learningconnection.philips.com/en/search/site/{}".format(Search_key)
html = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
urls=[item['href'] for item in soup.select('h3.title > a')]
print(len(urls))
price=[]
title=[]
for url in urls:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')
    if soup.select_one("[class*='field-price'] .even"):
        title.append(soup.select_one("h1#page-title").text)
        price.append(soup.select_one("[class*='field-price'] .even").text)
print(title)
print(price)
```

**Output**:

```
28
['NETWORK CONCEPTS (BIOMED)']
['4875.00']
```

Comment: Thanks, however when I change search keyword from "pinnacle" to "biomed", I'm only getting one result.  Whereas if I search on the website I will get 28...

Comment: @Vic : That is because there is not price tag present for other urls apart from one.If you `print(len(urls))` you will get all the 28 links.